# Round of number to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

How can I round of the number to 2 decimal places in below method ?

```
$('.total').each(function() {
      var amt = Number($(this).find(".amount").val().replace(/,/g, ''));
      subtotal += amt;
});
```

I tried to do `Number($(this).find(".amount").val().toFixed(2).replace(/,/g, ''));` but it's not working,

Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: It should be 1.17

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with `toFixed` func that it returns a string instead of a number.

There are a few possible solutions:

1. improved solution from you

   ```
   Number(val.toFixed(2))
   ```

   OR

   ```
   parseFloat(val.toFixed(2))
   ```
2. The solution in more Math way.

   ```
   Math.round(val*100)/100
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
const num = Number($(this).find(".amount").val().replace(/,/g, ''));
const amt = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

If value is a string:

`parseFloat(amt).toFixed(2);`

If value is a number:

`amt.toFixed(2);`

Or you can use solution from [MDN][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round]:

```
function roundToTwo(num) {    
    return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round
```

Comment: `.val()` would always return a string, not a number.

Comment: @VLAZ But `amt` is always a number in this case, because it is passed to `Number()` before assigning it to `amt`.